# Get the next sunday after a date. Why is my loop and adding date components not working correctly?

Tags: ios, while-loop, nsdatecomponents, dayofweek

I want to find the next sunday (or other weekday) after a given date

I have this code snippet:

```
            NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
            dayComponent.day = 1;
            NSCalendar *cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

            NSDate *adjustedBeginDate2 = _beginDate;
            while ([self getWeekDayOfDate:adjustedBeginDate2] != c) {
                adjustedBeginDate2 = [cal dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:adjustedBeginDate2 options:0];
            }
```

And this is the corresponding method:

```
- (int)getWeekDayOfDate:(NSDate *)myDate{
    NSCalendar* cal = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents* comp = [cal components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:myDate];
    return [comp weekday]; // 1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc.
}
```

I was expecting that the while loop will add 1 day on each iteration, until the condition evaluates to true and I should finally have `adjustedBeginDate2` being the next sunday (or other week day) following the `_beginDate`.
But this is not happening.
As I can see in the debugger each time the `dayComponent` is added, 2 days are added. So finally I end up with a much later sunday. What is wrong here?

Comment: Not going to try to analyze it, but you can do the job without a loop, by finding the current day of week, subtracting from Sunday, adding 7 if the result is less than zero, then adding that to the current day.  (Or something like that -- I may have a sign reversed somewhere.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: Yes, I was considering that, but I really like to know what is wrong with this simple loop?

Comment: It should be simple enough to debug.  Add NSLogs to see what the values are at each step.

Comment: I did this before posting here, and I stepprf through the code with the debugger. And, instead of 1 day added, 2 days are added.

Comment: Does it add two days on each iteration of the loop every time? Does it always add exactly multiples of 24 hours? What is c? I did look at the code you posted and nothing jumps out at me right now.